# Stimulsoft create Connection/Datasource not showing in report designer

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, reporting, stimulsoft

I want to create new report in Stimulsoft windows report designer but when i want to create new sql connection and new Datasource i cant see new connection or new datasource (Image Below)

[image: Image of designer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

In

> %Stimulsoft_Installation_Folder%\Tools\

Run

> Configurator.exe

and enabled all features, problem solved like a charm!